# Is there an R function for plotting three columns in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, tidyverse, geom-bar

I want to create a ggplot chart for this dataset:

```
head(df3)
  pedestrians motorist cyclist
1        1377     1100     200
```

And I did this:

```
ggplot(df3, aes(x = 1:3, y = c(pedestrians, motorist, cyclist))) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Accidents by Mode of Transportation") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Pedestrians", "Motorists", "Cyclists"))
```

And got this output:

```
Error in `geom_col()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `x` and `y`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not yet in tidy format. Below you see my approach to this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df3 <- data.frame(
  types= c("pedestrians","motorists", "cyclists"),
  accidents= c(1377,1100,200)
)

ggplot(df3, aes(x=types, y=accidents))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To get your data into a tidy format and plot it, you can use `pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df3 %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'Transport', values_to = 'Count') %>%
  ggplot(aes(Transport, Count)) +
  geom_col(fill = 'deepskyblue4') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]